# Java set the tommorrow id number to one

Tags: java

- My requirements:

  **ddmm + 2numbers**

  dd - day 
  mm - month 
  number - id number
- Examples of my output

  Today - 031201, 031202, 031203 ...

  Tommorrow - 041201
- **Properties file**: (idNumber.properties) 
  idNumber = 1;
- Here is the java code I did:

  ```
  public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      Test test = new Test();
      test.generate();
  }

  public String generate()
  {
      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMM");
      Date date = new Date(); 
      String currentDate = dateFormat.format(date); 

      String idNumber = generateIdNumber();

      String complete = currentDate + idNumber;
      return complete;
  }

  public String generateIdNumber(){
      Properties idNoProp = new Properties();     
      InputStream idNoInput = new FileInputStream("idNumber.properties"); //java   properties file
      idNoProp.load(idNoInput);

      String idNumber = idNoProp.getProperty("idNumber"); 
      int idNo = Integer.valueOf(idNumber);

      String result = "";
      if (idNo < 10) {
          result = "0" + idNo;
      } else {
          result = "" + idNo;
      }
      idNo++;

      OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("idNumber.properties");
      idNoProp.setProperty("idNumber", "" + idNo);
      idNoProp.store(output, null);

      return result;  
      }
  }
  ```
- My question is how do I reset the tommorrow id number start from 01?

Comment: Could you give us some more code? Like the complete method and how you use it.

Comment: You don't show enough code. You show some output of your code, but you don't show the code that produces the output.

Comment: First : You need to increment idNo not result

Comment: Seems you are not written proper code for getting todays output. Might be done to explain the problem area. It's better to pull complete code for better understanding and better answer too!

Comment: Dear all, I have edited my code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a property LAST_VISIT to your properties file. When you want to save the properties file, set the current date to it. In this way

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMM");
Date date = new Date(); 
String currentDate = dateFormat.format(date); 
idNoProp.setProperty("LAST_VISIT", currentDate);
```

Now in generateIdNumber() first check the value of LAST_VISIT. If it dose not equal currentDate , you must reset idNo. It works for everyday and every tommorow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a class static field to remember last used date for ids. Whenever you are in the next date relatively to the field you'll reset your idNo and update the last used date field (sorry for spelling)

Answer (score 0):

You can store a `Map<String,Integer>` that would hold the last index for each String representation of date. This way, each date would have its own indices starting with 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a scheduler which will reset the idNo at the start of each day, like at 00 hours. This will always gives you the consistent result, as if sometimes server/program restarts, it will not lead to any duplicate result.

Answer (score 0):

if you want format a number with two number, example '01' you could do this:

```
String.format("%02d", Integer.valueOf(idNumber));
```

instead of:

```
int idNo = Integer.valueOf(idNumber);
String result = "";
if (idNo < 10) {
   result = "0" + idNo;
} else {
   result = "" + idNo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
  Test test = new Test();
  System.out.println(""+test.generate());
  }

  public String generate() throws IOException
 {
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMM");
  Date date = new Date(); 
  String currentDate = dateFormat.format(date); 

  String idNumber = generateIdNumber(currentDate);

  String complete = currentDate + idNumber;
  return complete;
  }

   public String generateIdNumber(String currentDate) throws IOException{
   Properties idNoProp = new Properties();     
   InputStream idNoInput = new FileInputStream("idNumber.properties"); //java   properties file
   idNoProp.load(idNoInput);

   String idNumber = idNoProp.getProperty("idNumber"); 
   int idNo = Integer.valueOf(idNumber);
   String strOnlyDay = currentDate.substring(0, 2);
   System.out.println(strOnlyDay);// will return the first two characters of the day
   String result = "";
   if (idNo < 10) {
      result = "0" + idNo;
   } else {
    result = "" + idNo;
   }
  idNo++;

    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("idNumber.properties");
    if (strOnlyDay.equals("01")){
    idNo = 1;
    }

   idNoProp.setProperty("idNumber", "" + idNo);
   idNoProp.store(output, null);

   return result;  
 }
```

}

```
   Try to pass the value of your current date into generateIdNumber than see the code. I hope this will help. Hoping you will preserve the value of idNo.
```